# What actions did the KKK take against miscegenation after 1967?

Tags: united-states, racism, 1960s

Although the racial attitudes of the (third) KKK are well known, I haven't been able to find much about actions, demonstrations or speeches by the KKK against the repeal of anti-miscegenation laws in 1967, or against individual couples in those states.

What are some known anti-miscegenation actions, demonstrations or speeches by KKK members or leaders?

Comment: I do not think the KKK in 1967 was the politically active or powerful organization that you might it was -- in the 1920s, it might have been able to influence things.

Comment: They put up statues celebrating those who fought to preserve and expand slavery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Repeal is a nice way of saying it.  The anti-[miscegenation](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/miscegenation) laws of course were not repealed in 1967,  they were found unconstitutional on  June 12, 1967 when the Supreme Court heard the case [Lovings vs Virginia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loving_v._Virginia).  This is an important distinction because while it meant the laws were unenforceable, it did not mean they were repealed by the states. 17 states still enforced laws prohibiting mixed racial marriages in 1967 all from the South.  Only Maryland repealed its law in response to the Supreme Court case.  South Carolina repealed it's law in 1998.  Alabama, amended it's constitution in the year 2000.  And of coarse in 2009 a Louisiana justice of the peace refused to officiate a civil wedding because the couple was interracial. ( Governor Bobby Jindal and strong criticism forced his resignation in the same year.)

And while I disagree with the Jeff's comments that the KKK was not politically active or powerful organization in 67, they were under siege on multiple fronts at that time and in following years.

The 1964 murders of [Chaney, Goodman, and Schwerner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murders_of_Chaney,_Goodman,_and_Schwerner), three civil rights workers, in Mississippi. Put a huge public spot light on Klan activity.

In 1965, the House Un-American Activities Committee(*) started an investigation on the Klan, putting in the public spotlight its front organizations, finances, methods and divisions

In 1968 of coarse [President Johnson](http://www.politifact.com/texas/statements/2014/apr/14/barack-obama/lyndon-johnson-opposed-every-civil-rights-proposal/), a life long segregationist, passed the most sweeping civil rights bill in US history. [The 1968 civl rights act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Rights_Act_of_1968)

KKK groups began to oppose:

- court-ordered busing to desegregate schools
- affirmative action laws
- more open immigration
- legislation prohibiting legal segregation
- voting rights laws

The Klans resources were dwindling, and the number of issues they were against was mushrooming.

There were several prominent bombings and murders conducted by the Klan in 1967 but these were targeting the civil rights movement and its functionaries.  This is not to say interracial couples experienced no prejudice.  It’s likely most avoided the south knowing the possible consequences.  Those who did not and experienced the consequences would likely be chalked up to general rampant racism rather than Klan activity.

(*)["Ku Klux Klan Probe Begun"](https://library.cqpress.com/cqalmanac/login.php?requested=%2Fcqalmanac%2Fdocument.php%3Fid%3Dcqal65-875-26759-1261051). CQ Almanac (21 ed.). Washington, DC: 1517–1525. 1965.

Comment: So, to answer the original question, your answer is "they didn't"?

Comment: My answer is that discrimination against  interracial couples was so prevalent in the south there is no need to bring the Klan into it.  the South systemically discriminated and persecuted mixed race couples right up to the 21st century.  If that discrimination occurred at the hands of klan members or regular Southerners who weren't klan affiliated isn't reflected in the records of Klan activity post 1967.